# XSLT Code Needed for Styling text between 2 elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I hope someone can give me a hand.  This issue has been stumping me for several days now.  The root of my issue is that I want to add markup to all nodes in document order between 2 elements.

I have a document that has XML similar to this:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

When I use Oracle's 'markup' function which marks up search hits, and I search for the string 'John Doe', I get an XML result like this:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <FirstName><hitStart/>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe<hitEnd/></LastName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I want to transform this into XHTML that highlights the hit.  For example, the following XHTML would be a useful result:

```
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD>Mr. <b style="color:red">John Doe</b></TD>
  <TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>Tom Doe</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I've tried writing stylesheets that use apply-templates or named templates to navigate through the document, but I can't get them to work.  Using apply-templates is tricky because I can't pass a parameter that states whether or not the nodes are within the hitStart and hitEnd elements.  Using named templates is tricky because I need to handle text and element nodes differently, which I'm not able to do in XSLT 1.0.  Help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Thanks to everyone who helped!!!!  You guys are great!

Here's what I settled on:

```
<xsl:template match="/*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[preceding::*[self::hitStart or self::hitEnd][1][self::hitStart]
and following::*[self::hitStart or self::hitEnd][1][self::hitEnd]]">
    <span style="color:red;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hitStart|hitEnd">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: brianv, I completely changed the answer with a new solution. Is this better now? :)

Comment: Outstanding, Dimitre!!  Thank you so much.  That did the trick.  Since my real-life XML has attributes, even on the root node, I made a few tweaks.  Here's what's working for me:

Comment: `<xsl:template match="/*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[preceding::*[self::hitStart or self::hitEnd][1][self::hitStart]
    and following::*[self::hitStart or self::hitEnd][1][self::hitEnd]]">
    <search:hit><xsl:value-of select="."/></search:hit>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: `<xsl:template match="hitStart|hitEnd">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting.  I'm not sure how to make that look better on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "text()
      [preceding::*[self::hitStart or self::hitEnd][1][self::hitStart]
     and
       following::*[self::hitStart or self::hitEnd][1][self::hitEnd]
      ]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('*** ', ., ' ***')"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="hitStart|hitEnd">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied against the provided XML document:**

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <FirstName><hitStart/>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe<hitEnd/></LastName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**high-lights every text node in-between the `hitStart` and `hitEnd` elements -- by surrounding it with three asterisks and producing the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Employees>
   <Employee>
      <Title>Mr.</Title>
      <FirstName>*** John ***</FirstName>
      <LastName>*** Doe ***</LastName>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Title>Mr.</Title>
      <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**Explanation**:

Using and overriding the "fine-grained" identity rule.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre!  This is getting me close.  However, when the <hitStart> and <hitEnd> are not siblings like the example, then node-set is not picking up the nodes in-between.  I think this is the answer, but I have a little more tweaking to do.

Comment: @brianv, In this case use the axes: `following::` and `preceding::`

Comment: Thanks again.  That does the trick!  The last issue is that I want to run the logic for all hitStart/hitEnd pairs.  In other words, I won't know how many ordinal pairs there will be.  Right now, I'm looking into whether I could use apply-templates to catch the hitStart element, and then within that template match, I'm trying to see if I can use position() to figure out the ordinal number.  So far, no luck.  BTW, I love how you used the parenthesis to find all the hitStart and hitEnd elements first before determining the position.  I wasn't aware that parenthesis could be used like that.  Thx!

Comment: perhaps I can use position() to get the relative position such as:(//hitStart)[position()]/following-sibling::node()
   [count(.|(//hitEnd)[position()]/preceding-sibling::node()) = count((//hitEnd)[position()]/preceding-sibling::node())].  I'll give it a try once my development environment starts responding again :(

Comment: Nevermind.  That won't work unless I can figure out the logic for stating that the hitStart's position should match the hitEnd's position.

Comment: @brianv, This is quite simple: `(//hitStart)[1]` has matching `(//hitEnd)[1]` -- and the same for 2, 3, ...

Comment: That's true, but I think I need something more generic.  For example, I think the following would get me what I need: (//hitStart)[1]/following::node() [count(.|(//hitEnd)[1]/preceding::node()) = count((//hitEnd)[1]/preceding::node()) | (//hitStart)[2]/following::node() [count(.|(//hitEnd)[2]/preceding::node()) = count((//hitEnd)[2]/preceding::node()) | (//hitStart)[3]/following::node() [count(.|(//hitEnd)[3]/preceding::node()) = count((//hitEnd)[3]/preceding::node()) ...  However, I don't know how many hitStart/hitEnd pairs there will be.  There may be hundreds.

Comment: @brianv, But this is something very basic: `<xsl:for-each select="//hitStart"><xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position"/> Then the XPath expression using $vPos as index </xsl:for-each>`

Comment: @brianv, I completely changed the answer with a new solution. Is this better now? :)

Comment: Outstanding, Dimitre!! Thank you so much. That did the trick. Since my real-life XML has attributes, even on the root node, I made a few tweaks. See my code above for my final version.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but you could do something quick and dirty like...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FirstName[hitStart]">
        <span class="alert"><xsl:value-of select="."/>&#160;</span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FirstName">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>&#160;
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LastName[hitEnd]">
        <span class="alert"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LastName">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Employees/Employee">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Title"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName | LastName"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick.  That appears to work for the example, but I should have mentioned that I'll have a wide varienty of use cases.  For example, I may have <FirstName>asdf<hitStart/>Mary<hitEnd/>qwer<hitStart/>Beth<hitEnd/></FirstName>.  Also, the elements may have any name.  There's no defined DTD.  I'll want to add formatting to all text between the hitStart and hitEnd elements and no formatting for any other text.  I'm curious, why did you use span?  I'm not as familiar with that HTML element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that uses disable output escaping to prevent errors starting an element without an ending, and ending an element without a start element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Employees">
        <TABLE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee"/>
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <TR>
            <TD><xsl:apply-templates/></TD>
        </TR>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hitStart">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'&lt;b style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;'"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hitEnd">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'&lt;/b&gt;'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks, Joepie!  I worked out a solution from Dimitre's suggestion above, so I'm not sure if this would've worked for me.  I haven't used disable-output-escaping before, so this is an interesting idea I'll think about.

Comment: How did you solve the bold start tag and end tag problem with Dimitre solution?

Comment: Joepie, I updated the solution above in my question.  I realized last night that I left that out.  Sorry.